HTTPS on Dynamic IP Address using AWS
I have a system that needs to have an HTTPS connection, the problem is that it uses dynamic IP sim cards, and the system hosts a server on this IP.
I am planning to load Greengrass onto the system and use this to connect to AWS but I am not sure where to go from there, or even if this route I'm taking is feasible. Is there some tool like a DDNS that AWS has and how would that be implemented with Greengrass?

Just to clarify... Are you saying that something running on AWS will need to establish outbound connections to these devices, but they can change IP address? Or will the devices establish an inbound connection to something running on AWS?

"needs to have an HTTPS connection" - WHICH DIRECTION! How much downtime can you afford? What is your lease time?
